# Can't run Docker from terminal - exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

Linux Ubuntu 22.04

I installed Docker like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for alexeij:               
(Reading database ... 483879 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack docker-desktop-4.16.2-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-desktop (4.16.2-95914) over (4.16.2-95914) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of docker-desktop:
 docker-desktop depends on qemu-system-x86 (>= 5.2.0); however:
  Package qemu-system-x86 is not installed.
 docker-desktop depends on docker-ce-cli; however:
  Package docker-ce-cli is not installed.
 docker-desktop depends on pass; however:
  Package pass is not installed.
 docker-desktop depends on uidmap; however:
  Package uidmap is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package docker-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

And try run docker from terminal

```
docker
```

but get error:

```
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
Current PATH : /home/alex/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:/home/alex/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/alex/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:
```

I can successfully run Docker from Menu

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

if want to run Docker Desktop in terminal, should run:

`systemctl --user start docker-desktop`

#### 2.

if want to use docker engine, this will help.

[install docker engine on ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#:%7E:text=/dev/null-,Install%20Docker%20Engine,-Update%20the%20apt)

After this,checkout the version and executable file

`which docker && docker verion`

Also, make sure docker is running

`systemctl status docker`

Comment: I need to install Docker Desktop, but get errors

Comment: @Alexei from your error info, these packages must be installed: **qemu-system-x86,docker-ce-cli,pass,uidmap.** And i found [this may hava some help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409192/cannot-install-docker-desktop-on-ubuntu-22-04)